# How to handle an iframe without an id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

Currently I've got a website with an `iframe` loaded from another site into my website. The loaded iframed site requires a button, which has an id called 'accept', to be clicked. (cookies)

Of course the user should not click this button twice, so I want to click this button automatically once MY page is loaded.

**Problem:**

The loaded `iframe` from the other site has no ID neither NAME tag.
How can I click this button on page load?

**Code which I've tried, but does not work:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#accept").click(); 
    });
</script>
```

I've readed on the internet it's possible to listen to an `iframe` without an ID. But I have no clue on how to write this into code.

I've been searching google the whole day. I can't get a solution.

Hopefully someone can help me on my encountered problem. A fixed code with explaination/documentation would do it for me.

Best regards.

Comment: Can't you simply select it with `$('iframe')` and trigger your click inside ? `$('iframe').contents().find('#accept').click()`. If you have multiple Iframes, just select the n-th one with `$('iframe').eq(n+1)`

Comment: @Zenoo Thank you. I received this error: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.`. Can this be solved? Or can this simply not?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: Thank you @TheAlpha. Seems my idea is not working ;-). I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really a solution, but it's an answer on my question:
[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

> You can't access an  with Javascript, it would be a huge
>   security flaw if you could do it. For the same-origin policy browsers
>   block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to the `load` event of an iframe. I suppose there is only one iframe in your HTML page, so the following can work without any issue:

```
$(function() {
  $('iframe').load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('#accept').click();
  });
});
```

Note that you need to access the contents of the iframe using `contents()` method.